# Python Chat Server with Threads and multiclients

Tags: python, sockets

My goal is to take a provided framework python file and add the functionality to make a **chat server** that handles multiple clients. I have done edits in the chat_output, server, and client functions.

First step is to get the client to connect without issues.
Then I would need to add a raw_input() call so that a user can type something, send it to the server, and then have the server sendall() to the clients.

```
import socket
import time

def timestamp():
    result = int(time.time())
    return result


class Stream(object):
    " abstract "
    def write(self,data):
        pass
    def read(self):
        pass

class TCPStream(Stream):
    def __init__(self,the_socket):
        self.s = the_socket
        self.address = None
    def read(self,amount=None):
        if amount is None:
            return self.s.recv(4096)
        else:
            return self.s.recv(amount)
    def set_address(self,address):
        self.address = address
    def get_address(self):
        return self.address
    def write(self,data):
        self.s.sendall(data)
    def __del__(self):
        self.s.close()
    def shutdown(self):
        self.s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)

class Socket(object):
    pass

class TCPBaseSocket(Socket):
    def __init__(self,port):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.port = port

class TCPReceivingSocket(TCPBaseSocket):
    def __init__(self,port,address=''):
        super().__init__(port)
        self.s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.s.bind((address,self.port))
        self.s.listen(1)
    def connection(self):
        sc, sockname = self.s.accept()
        result = TCPStream(sc)
        result.set_address(sockname)
        return result

class TCPSendingSocket(TCPBaseSocket):
    def __init__(self,port,address):
        super().__init__(port)
        self.s.connect((address,port))
        self._stream = TCPStream(self.s)
        self._stream.set_address((address,port))
    def stream(self):
        return self._stream

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse
    import threading
    import sys

    def chat_input(stream):
        """
            Enter your code here, shouldn't need to be more than 10 lines of code
        """

        pass

    def chat_output(stream):        
        """
        Enter your code here, shouldn't need to be more than 10 lines of code
        """

        #stream = TCPStream(stream)
        s = TCPStream(stream)
        while True:
            data = s.read()    #s.recv(4096)
            if not data:
                print("Disconnected from chat server")
                break
            #stream.write(data)      #sendall(data)



    def server(interface,port):
        """
        Enter your code here, shouldn't need to be more than 10 lines of code
        """

        tsc = TCPReceivingSocket(port, interface)
        print("Server is running.....\n")

        addr = tsc.connection().get_address()
        print(addr, " is now connected!\n")


        server_input_thread = threading.Thread(target = chat_input, args = (tsc,))
        server_output_thread = threading.Thread(target = chat_output, args = (tsc,))

        server_input_thread.start()
        server_output_thread.start()
        server_input_thread.join()
        server_output_thread.join()

    def client(interface,port):
        """
        Enter your code here, shouldn't need to be more than 10 lines of code
        """
        tsc = TCPSendingSocket(port, interface)


        client_input_thread = threading.Thread(target = chat_input, args=(tsc,))
        client_output_thread = threading.Thread(target = chat_output, args=(tsc,))

        client_input_thread.start()
        client_output_thread.start()
        client_input_thread.join()
        client_output_thread.join()

    choices = {'client':client,'server':server}
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Chat via TCP')
    parser.add_argument('role',choices=choices,help="which role to take")
    parser.add_argument('host',help='interface the server listens at; host the client sends to')
    parser.add_argument('-p',metavar='PORT',type=int,default=1060,help='TCP port (default 1060)')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    function=choices[args.role]
    function(args.host,args.p)
```

For those who are running this, use the command line:

> python3 [filename].py server localhost
>
> python3 [filename].py client localhost

---

When I run:
The server connects. Now how do I work with the TCPStream object? The parameter is supposed to be passed a 'stream' object but it's a TCPR/Ssocket

Server:

```
E:\School\CSIS\440\Assignment7>py talk.py server localhost
Server is running.....

('127.0.0.1', 53829)  is now connected!

Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\School\Python\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "E:\School\Python\lib\threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "talk.py", line 85, in chat_output
    data = s.read()    #s.recv(4096)
  File "talk.py", line 22, in read
    return self.s.recv(4096)
AttributeError: 'TCPReceivingSocket' object has no attribute 'recv'

Exception ignored in: <bound method TCPStream.__del__ of <__main__.TCPStream obj
ect at 0x010B68B0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "talk.py", line 32, in __del__
    self.s.close()
AttributeError: 'TCPReceivingSocket' object has no attribute 'close'

E:\School\CSIS\440\Assignment7>
```

Client:

```
E:\School\CSIS\440\Assignment7>py talk.py client localhost
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\School\Python\lib\threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "E:\School\Python\lib\threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "talk.py", line 85, in chat_output
    data = s.read()    #s.recv(4096)
  File "talk.py", line 22, in read
    return self.s.recv(4096)
AttributeError: 'TCPSendingSocket' object has no attribute 'recv'

Exception ignored in: <bound method TCPStream.__del__ of <__main__.TCPStream obj
ect at 0x00C068F0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "talk.py", line 32, in __del__
    self.s.close()
AttributeError: 'TCPSendingSocket' object has no attribute 'close'

E:\School\CSIS\440\Assignment7>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks, including line numbers that match up to the code you posted. "Abbreviating" may remove vital information. Also, please post the **exact** code you're running - don't comment out sections you're running in reality. You really also should get rid of all those extraneous `pass` statements.

Comment: The abbreviations were to simply remove the imported threading.py file lines. There was only one pass statement that I left in there accidentally -- chat_input has not been written.

Comment: **PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**. Copy and paste the text into your question. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question. See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1426065) for more information.

Comment: Now is everything up to par for you?